# lightning-input firing two onclick events in Lightning Web Component

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-oss

I am receiving two events when I am clicking lightning-input checkbox. This behavior is the same in Salesforce as well as on the LWC playground.

Wherever if use html checkbox then I receive event only one time.

Anyone else is having the same problem?
Here is the code in LWC playground: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/lsOssohh3/2/edit

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [specification](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/specification) of lightning-input, it looks like there is no native `onclick` event.

Its recommended  that you should be using `onchange` instead.

HTML:

```
<template>
    <lightning-input type="checkbox" label="Lightning Checkbox"  onchange={handleBulletPointsInput2}>
        </lightning-input>

        <input type="checkbox" onclick={handleBulletPointsInput2}>HTML Checkbox</input>
</template>
```

Js:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class InputCheckboxBasic extends LightningElement {
    handleBulletPointsInput2(){
        console.log('--handleBulletPointsInput21--');
    }
}
```

Playground Link : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/lsOssohh3/5/edit

**Reason why its firing two events onclick:**

In normal html-checkbox, the check uncheck only work when you click on the checkbox.

In `lightning-input` the check-uncheck work even on click of Label. Both checkbox and label react to click  as they both are children of div/span that handles the onclick  event and propagates it down to all reactive children

Comment: Hi! I faced the same issue and `onchange` does not work for me. I finally solve the problem using `oncommit`.

Answer (score 0):

```
handleBulletPointsInput2(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('--handleBulletPointsInput21--');
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to provide context. Code only answers are typically viewed as low quality and often deleted.

Comment: This prevents the checkbox to marked as checked

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I don't know why but `onchange`, as suggested by Pranay Jaiswal didn't work for me. After some looking `oncommit` worked just perfect.